# Умный фильтр не фильтрует Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

При включении ЧПУ не сбрасывался фильтр при нажатии "СБРОС". SEF_SET_FILTER и SEF_DEL_FILTER были пустыми, указал правило SEF_RULE, УРЛ стал нормальным и сброс происходит по урлу. Но сами товары при установлении фильтра - сбрасываются, а урл при этом  /414/filter/forma_vypuska-is-8b19aec3-9bf0-11e9-80d0-8bb57185d5a2/apply/ а товары выводятся все. В чем может быть проблема, вот настройки фильтра: (сам фильтр находится в list_elements)

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.smart.filter", 
    "inherit_sibagro", 
    array(
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "N",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_MODE" => "A",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_TYPE" => "AUTO",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "Y",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
        "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "vertical",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "28",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog_1c",
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
        "POPUP_POSITION" => "left",
        "PREFILTER_NAME" => "smartPreFilter",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(
        ),
        "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N",
        "SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "SECTION_TITLE" => "-",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "XML_EXPORT" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "inherit_sibagro",
        "SEF_RULE" => "/manufacturers/".$arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_ID"]."/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/",
        "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_ID_2" => isset($arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_ID"])?$arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_ID"]:0,
        "SECTION_CODE_PATH" => "",
        "SMART_FILTER_PATH" => ""
    ),
    false
);?>
```